# Summing multiple columns

Tags: mysql

**user table**
user_id

**entry**
user_id
points_a
points_b

```
SELECT user.*, 
(SUM(entry.points_a) + SUM(entry.points_b)) as points_total
FROM user
LEFT JOIN entry on entry.user_id = entry.user_id
```

..is what I'm trying to do — get a total count of all points that a user has. The field type for points is INT. This Doesn't seem to work?

Comment: What do you expect it to do, and what happens instead?

Comment: "This Doesn't seem to work?" --- so instead of trying to run it in mysql you came here and asked? Do you ask about each sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have no columns in user except the ID, the join really serves no purpose.

```
select userid, SUM(points_a) + SUM(points_b) as total
from entry
group by userid
```

This will give you what you are looking for.  If you need more fields from the user table that you just didn't show, you can do the join and add those fields to the select.

I think what you were missing was the Group By clause though.